# Tinylog: Getting "LOGGER ERROR: Illegal severity level" on Json writer

Tags: tinylog

I tried implementing the below mentioned code in my system. I'm getting a error like:
LOGGER ERROR: Invalid charset: UTF-8
LOGGER ERROR: Illegal severity level: error

```
`writer3               = json
writer3.level         = error            
writer3.file          = logs/log-{count}.json
writer3.field.level   = level             
writer3.field.source  = {class}.{method}()
writer3.field.message = message           
writer3.charset       = UTF-8         
writer3.append        = true          
writer3.buffered      = true`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for the errors are the white space at the end of the lines in `writer3.level         = error`             and `writer3.charset       = UTF-8`         . Just remove all spaces and tabs behind `error` and `UTF-8`. Afterwards, the JSON writer will work without any errors :)

PS: In the next version of tinylog 2.4, the logging framework will trim such whitespace automatically.